Identify this hose reel holder combination
Can anyone identify this construction, or do the items not originally belong together?
The colors are a bit off, with the claw being more brown-ish than the reel holder.
Underneath the holder, it says 2584 and "1 01"


The left part is 2651 : Hook Slider, Arm ,
in combination with Part # 2584 String Reel 2 x 2 Holder
it appears in two sets

9365 Community Vehicles

6668 Recycle Truck



Nice find! Note though, that the configuration in the photo is the opposite (the thread enters the other side of the arm) of those of the two models - which are actually the same design, just released once as a standalone set and once as part of a collection.
